# how to scrape product gallery image link on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, image, image-processing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape product gallery images url from this website using BeautifulSoup4 https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/awei-y336-portable-wireless-bluetooth-mini-speaker-charging-cable-i128428097-s1048302559.html?search=1 but I din't find any way. Some products have 3 image and some have more. [image]

can anybody tell me how I will scrape gallery images url using BeautifulSoup?

here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/awei-y336-portable-wireless-bluetooth-mini-speaker-charging-cable-i128428097-s1048302559.html?search=1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
container = soup.find_all("body")
for items in container:
        title = items.find("div",{"class":"pdp-product-title"}).text
        price = items.find('span', attrs={'class':'pdp-price'}).text.strip(" ৳")
        print(title,price)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: What have you done? This is no a software service.

Comment: Juan I already build my code which can extract product title, description and others information from this page but I don't know how to scrape product gallery image url on beautifulsoup so that I post it here for getting help. I am a newbie who just start learning code.

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't provide a Minimal reproducible example. That way people don't have start from zero, and they can reuse your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. This is at least the 3rd question you've asked about scraping this exact website. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials.** See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Juan Javier Santos Ochoa  I updated my post and added my code please see

Comment: AMC here I am not for receive free code writing service. I am here for improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this page is complicated to scrape because they have the information You want embedded in a lot of (JavaScript) code. The good thing is that it's easy to identify the images because they have a pattern: https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/\w+.jpg, so we can use regular expression to extract these URLs. The problem is that probably you'll get more images that you want, unless you make more filters to get exactly what You want. This is a way to do it, the rest is on you:

```py
import requests
import json
import re
import urllib 
import os

url = 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/awei-y336-portable-wireless-bluetooth-mini-speaker-charging-cable-i128428097-s1048302559.html?search=1'
resp1 = requests.get(url)
text = resp1.text
images = list(set(re.findall(r"https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/\w+.jpg", text)))
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, filename=f'img{i}.jpg')
```

Comment: not working/ getting this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/img0.jpg'

Comment: create a folder named `images`

Comment: I modified, give a try. If you have an error, please tell what error.

Comment: Juan Javier Santos Ochoa Thank you but the problem is it downloading images.Instead of download  I want it will be print image url